# Find maximum triplet in an array

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array of numbers `[1,2,6,4,105,111,1024]` I want to check all possible triplets `a,b,c` such that `b%a ==0 and c%b ==0`. For such triplets get the middle element b. Now I want to return the maximum possible b for such triplets.

For this array the valid triplets are :

indices:

```
(0,1,2) = middle item = 2
(0,1,3) = middle item = 2
(0,1,6) = middle item = 2
(0,3,6) = middle item = 4
(1,3,6) = middle item = 4
```

So the maximum value is 4 is the answer.

Here is my code:

```
int process(List<Integer> list) {
   int n = list.size();
   int max = -1;
   for(int i=0; i<n-2; i++) {
    int a = list.get(i);
    boolean valid = true;
    for(int j=i+1; j<n-1; j++) {
        int b = list.get(j);
        valid = b % a == 0;
        for(int k=j+1; valid && k<n; k++) {
            int c = list.get(k);
            if(c % b ==0) {
                max = Math.max(max, b);
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

How to reduce the time complexity for this code.

**constraints:**

size of the input list is 1 to 10^5.
Each element in the list is also 1 to 10^5
Repetitions are allowed for input elements.

Comment: Sort the input. Iterate backwards through the sorted input. The first triple you find is the greatest.

Comment: It doesn't seem they are allowed to sort the array, as the triplets are ordered. Can you clarify, OP?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, if sorted the middle element positions will change, so sorting is not allowed for my task.

Comment: Is there repetition, or is the list a permutation of the integers from 1 to 10^5?

Comment: @Dave, repetitions are allowed for my input list

Comment: @learner Did our answers work?

Answer (score 2):

`c % b = 0` and `b % a = 0` means `a` is the lowest factor OR a possible GCD of both `b` and `c`. However, since we need to find the maximum greatest value of the middle element, we will take a different route.

- We put all the elements of the array in the hashMap with a boolean falsy value by default.
- For each element in `arr`, we check with all it's factors by iterating till square root of this number.
- If any of the factor exists already in the map, we perform one more check as to whether this factor has a factor of it's own present in the array. This way, the current factor at hand makes it the *middle element* of the triplet.
- We keep taking maximum of those and return the answer. We return `-1` if no such triplet exists.

**Snippet:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] arr = { 1,2,6,4,105,111,1024};
      System.out.println(solve(arr));
  }
  
  private static int solve(int[] arr){
    Map<Integer,Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
    int max = -1;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length; ++i){
      boolean factorExists = false;
      
      for(int j = 1; j * j <= arr[i]; ++j){
        if(arr[i] % j == 0 && map.getOrDefault(j, false)){
          max = Math.max(max, j);
        }
        
        int cousin = arr[i] / j;
        if(arr[i] % j == 0 && arr[i] % cousin == 0 && map.getOrDefault(cousin, false)){
          max = Math.max(max, cousin);
        }
        
        factorExists = factorExists || arr[i] % j == 0 && map.containsKey(j) || arr[i] % j == 0 && arr[i] % cousin == 0 && map.containsKey(cousin);
      }
      
      map.putIfAbsent(arr[i], false);
      map.put(arr[i], map.get(arr[i]) || factorExists);
    }
    
    return max;
  }
}
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/java/3yce4f4jz)

**Time Complexity:** O(n<sup>1.5</sup>) since we walk through till square root of each element.

**Space Complexity:** O(n) since we store all the elements of the array in the map.

Comment: The time complexity looks wrong. If the maximum element in the array is `m`, the complexity would be `O(n * (m^0.5))`

Comment: @AbhinavMathur n and m can be upto a maximum of 10^5. Right?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur True, but in this case we are given `n == m == 10**5`.  So it works out.  Modulo bugs, of course.

Comment: @btilly Yup, fixed those modulo issues now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more efficient approach based on what @nice_dev already did.  The improvement is to create a table of factors instead of checking up to the square root of each number.

If you have `n` numbers of size at most `m`, this approach is `O((n+m) log(m))`.

```
def find_max_mid(numbers):
    # Find all potential factors.
    max_n = max(numbers)
    factors = {}
    saw_n = set()
    for n in numbers:
        if n not in saw_n:
            for m in range(n, max_n+1, n):
                if m in factors:
                    factors[m].append(n)
                else:
                    factors[m] = [n]
            saw_n.add(n)

    max_mid = -1
    has_factor = set()
    saw_n = set() # Reset

    for n in numbers:
        for f in factors[n]:
            if f in saw_n:
                if max_mid < f and f in has_factor:
                    max_mid = f
                has_factor.add(n)
        saw_n.add(n)

    return max_mid


print(find_max_mid([1,2,6,4,105,111,1024]))
print(find_max_mid([3,9,27,32,64]))
print(find_max_mid([1,2,3]))

print(find_max_mid(list(range(1, 100000))))
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using multiple for loops use single for loop and a HashMap to keep the modulo results for each position and with that you can do the same thing with O(n) time complexity

Comment: I need to check the positions for 3 elements, so will hashmap and modulo works? can you please share the code for this approach

Comment: yes you ca n use hashmap, try doing it, you can do it, I Intentionally didn't add code in answer because it looks like some homework task for you, so you should try to optimize it with my hint. As there is no fun in getting ready code, and your name is Learner so I assume you will enjoy writing it yourself.

Comment: Since there are many modulo results for each element, how can you claim this would be O(n)!?

Comment: But modulo with what number and how to store the processed modules?